# Get a circle's coordinates besides mouse pointer

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get a circle's coordinates besides of the mouse pointer in real time.

I wrote the codes of getting the coordinates of the mouse pointer but I can't get the coordinates of circle besides it.

Here is my code.

```js
        var item = document.querySelector("#moveItem");
        var itemRect = item.getBoundingClientRect();

        document.addEventListener("mousemove", followMouse, false);

        function followMouse(e) {
            var xPos = e.pageX - itemRect.width / 35;
            var yPos = e.pageY - itemRect.height / 35;

            console.log(xPos + " " + yPos);

            item.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
        }
        
        window.onload = init;
function init() {
 if (window.Event) {
 document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE);
 }
 document.onmousemove = getCursorXY;
}

function getCursorXY(e) {
 document.getElementById('cursorX').value = (window.Event) ? e.pageX : event.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft) ;
 document.getElementById('cursorY').value = (window.Event) ? e.pageY : event.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop);
}
```

```css
body {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
        #moveItem {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: #FF3333;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cursorX" size="3"> X-position of the Mouse
<input type="text" id="cursorY" size="3"> Y-position of the Mouse
<input type="text" id="circleX" size="3"> X-position of the Circle
<input type="text" id="circleY" size="3"> Y-position of the Circle

<div id="moveItem"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.getElementById('moveItem').getBoundingClientRect();` to get the coordinates of your circle. The values returned are the `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` measurements of the circle, so calculating the circle's centre coordinates is as simple as finding the average of each pair.

To update your `circleX` and `circleY` inputs, add the following code to your `getCursorXY(e)` function:

```
var circleSize = document.getElementById('moveItem').getBoundingClientRect();

document.getElementById('circleX').value = ((circleSize.left + circleSize.right) / 2);
document.getElementById('circleY').value = ((circleSize.top + circleSize.bottom) / 2);
```